Where does this jumbotron like come from?
I have installed fresh Laravel backpack and it seems I have a different design than the default one (or I made something wrong somewhere).
I can't find where this black/blue background come from (above the light grey). On dark mode, it's uniform.


you active "Tabler" theme, if you need to change follow the instructions in docs
Options are:
backpack.theme-tabler
backpack.theme-coreuiv2
backpack.theme-coreuiv4

Cheers.

I have tabler-theme enabled already

The setting for this is in config/backpack/theme-tabler.php, layout key. I saw it after looking again and again...
